# Can't detect enter press on mobile (textarea)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

To detect enter press I'm using simple solution:

```
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    // do something
}
```

On desktop it works properly anywhere. On tablet, smartphone - too - but, if it comes to textarea this doesn't work.

It became a problem since few last chrome updates.

So, when you press enter from mobile you see just new line "\n", but no function execution.

So, how to detect enter on textarea on mobile devices on latest chrome version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it may be a Chrome specific bug, those might be some *possible* soloutions:

1. Check for `e.which` as well:

   ```
   var key = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;
   if (key == 13) {
       // do something
   }
   ```
2. Try a different event: e.g. if you're using `keyUp`, try `keyPress`

---

If that still doesn't work you might need a workaround for that, if the detection is important. You could keep track of the value and detect once "\n" gets added to the textarea using the `input` event.

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('your-textarea');
var textareaValue = textarea.value;
var textareaLines = getLines(textareaValue);

function getLines(str) {
    // This uses RegEx to match new lines.
    // We use || [] because it would otherwise fail if there weren't
    // any line breaks yet.

    return (str.match(/[\n\r]/g) || []).length;
}

textarea.addEventListener('input', function() {
    var newValue = textarea.value;
    var newLines = getLines(newValue);

    if (newLines > textareaLines
        && newValue.length == textareaValue.length + 1) {

        // We also check that the new length is only one
        // character longer to not fire this new line event
        // after a copy-paste with a new line character.

        doSomething();
    }

    textareaValue = newValue;
    textareaLines = newLines;
}, false);
```

Comment: Your possible solution weren't helpful, because I've found out that android keyboard (or it's chrome fault, not sure) don't emit "keypress, keydown" events each time you "press" it. You can get "e.keyCode==229" sometimes, but that's another story.

Trick with a value processing works well, thanks for posting the code I was thinking about)

Answer (score 1):

if like me you are using react, `onKeyPress={e => e.key}` works.

`e.key` returns "Enter" on browser and mobile

`e.code` returns "Enter" on browser only