# How to detect an 'Enter' key press in a textarea on mobile (Chrome on Android)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to detect whenever the 'Enter' key is pressed within a `textarea`. On desktop, I can listen for the `keydown` event and and check if `e.key === 'Enter'` or `e.keyCode === 13`.

However this doesn't seem to work reliably on mobile (Chrome on Android).

If I input a few characters and press 'Enter', key is undefined and keyCode is 229 ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTHPC.png)). keyCode 229 appears to be the same for any key.

What's strange is that if I end the last word with a period or space, then press 'Enter', both key and keyCode seem to capture that 'enter' was pressed ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRpVH.png))

I've also tried listening for the `beforeinput` event and checking `e.inputType === 'insertLineBreak'` but this has the same issue (it seems to register only if I end the last word with a period or space before pressing enter).

Here's a sandbox where I've setup this scenario: https://playcode.io/1262618

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598633/cant-detect-enter-press-on-mobile-textarea) suggests I could write a custom function using RegEx to check for line breaks, however given the answer is 7 years old I'm wondering if there's now a more straightforward way to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't detect enter press on mobile (textarea)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598633/cant-detect-enter-press-on-mobile-textarea)

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal that answer suggests checking e.which or e.keyCode === 13. I've tried both of those but unfortunately they only work if I end the last word with a period or space before pressing 'Enter', otherwise they return 229. The other suggestion is to implement a custom RegEx functoin to check for newlines, which someone has recommended here as well. Looks like I may need to do that.

Comment: @Yogi thanks for checking. Perhaps it's something specific to my device or version of Android (Pixel 5 running Android 13).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This will do the work

```js
function newEnterHandler(callback) {
  let countEnter = 0;
  return event => {
    const newCount = (event.target.value.match(/\n/g) || []).length;
    if (countEnter < newCount) callback(event);
    countEnter = newCount;
  }
}

const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');

const handler = newEnterHandler((event) => {
  console.log("Enter pressed");
  console.log("Current Value:\n", event.target.value);
  //
  // Your Code Here
  //
});

textarea.addEventListener('input', handler);
```

Comment: Thanks Vahan. I was hoping there may be a way to detect this without the custom RegEx, but it now seems like this is the best approach.

Comment: Thanks, it is really useful. marking the question for me.

Comment: Thnx for the feedback folks 

Answer (score 0):

I ran into these problems some time ago with an app that I developed...

The issue is that different events occur depending on the operating system of the device, the browser... etc.

I finished with all the problems by developing my own keyboard (a div with buttons and my own onClick, onPress... etc).

It is a lot of work? not so much, you stop having problems and it works for any device.

There are also several npm packages that generate a keyboard to your liking and preferences.